# jScrollPane doesn't function with custom .scroll

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I have added [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to a div that already has a certain amount of jQuery attached to it.

jsFiddle [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkAw8/).

The scrollbar styling appears, but the scrollbar doesn't move, in-fact it's not even 'grabbable' and my existing functionality fails. However, I don't get any JS errors.

Comment out `$('.block-product-gallery .block-content').jScrollPane();` in the html example above and my previous functionality returns (although in jsFiddle the click function doesn't work - it does in my local browsers).

My first suspect is my hacky `.scroll` monitoring, but removing it doesn't solve the problem and without any clear errors I'm increasingly stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had a play with your jsfiddle and got it a lot closer to working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkAw8/1/

The main thing that was causing problems was the `position: absolute` on the rule for `.block.block-product-gallery.non-static .block-inner .block-content .products`. This meant that jScrollPane was having trouble calculating the width of it's contents (since the contents were positioned absolutely they weren't taking up any space inside the scrollpane and hence scrolling wasn't necessary.

I also changed the `overfow-x` and `overflow-y` to just plain `overflow` - I haven't done much testing with the direction specific overflows and they may not work correctly.

I'm not sure exactly what your productGallery plugin is meant to be doing but I think that it might not be working... Rather than listening for the `scroll` event you can try listening for the `jsp-scroll-y` event (see [events in jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html))

Comment: Thanks vitch, that's a (big) step closer. The productGallery plugin allows the user to scroll through the div with a back and forward button. Each will grey out when start or end of the div is encountered. The need for the scroll bar, unfortunately, came after the initial creation of this plugin. Your code fixes the scroll bar, but the buttons remain broken, I'll explore your suggestions.

Comment: You may be able to do without the productGallery plugin and just reproduce it's functionality with jScrollPane. Here is one example put together by someone with help on the mailing list: http://www.agdd.com.au/ - also see http://www.jsfiddle.net/dzvSC/5/ and http://web-sec.de/jq/par_final-2-28.html (more in this thread: http://bit.ly/dI7J1E ) - hope those help!